# Tippy.js not displaying content from the data attribute?

Tags: javascript, tooltip, tippyjs

I've installed tippy.js to handle my tooltips, however I am struggling to get the tooltips to display the content set from the data attribute. My default tooltip is working fine, however when I initialise by a class, to be able to add a different style to the tooltip, it doesn't get the content from the tooltip.

```
tippy.setDefaults({
    animation: 'scale',
    animateFill: false,
    maxWidth: 240,
    duration: 0,
    arrow: false,
})

tippy('.js-tippy-reviews', {
    theme: 'reviews',
    animation: 'scale',
    animateFill: false,
    maxWidth: 240,
    duration: 0,
    arrow: false,
})
```

If I add the content method to tippy it will display, however since the content of the tooltip is dynamic, i need to set it on the data attribute. I am unsure how to pass the data attribute from the element into tippy.

```
content: this.dataset.tippy
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="js-tippy-reviews reviews-notification" data-tippy="2 Pending Reviews"></div>
```

Comment: Could you provide the DOM element?

Comment: I've added the html to the question :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could add the onShow() function and read it from the instance and set the content from the reference dataset.

```js
tippy.setDefaults({
      animation: 'scale',
      animateFill: false,
      maxWidth: 240,
      duration: 0,
      arrow: false,
  });

  tippy('.js-tippy-reviews', {
      theme: 'reviews',
      animation: 'scale',
      animateFill: false,
      maxWidth: 240,
      duration: 0,
      arrow: false,
      onShow(instance) {
        instance.popper.hidden = instance.reference.dataset.tippy ? false : true;
       instance.setContent(instance.reference.dataset.tippy);
      }
  });
 
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn-change-data").click(function()
  {
    $(".js-tippy-reviews").attr("data-tippy",$("#test-input").val());
  })
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@4"></script>

<div class="js-tippy-reviews  reviews-notification" data-tippy="test">CONTENT</div>


<input type="text" id="test-input" />
<button id="btn-change-data">Change data-tippy</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @Recep Karadas :)

Comment: I've just noticed that using the above code, that if the data attribute is not present, it will still show the tooltip but it will be empty. Is there anyway we can prevent the tooltip from showing on the element if there is no data attribute? Guess we could just remove the class?

Comment: Since you have the instance and luckily they are providing a hidden attribute, we are able to use that. Just added a textbox and button to change the data attribute dynamically for testing purpose :)

Answer (score 1):

This solution works

```
tippy('.js-tippy-reviews', {
    content: (reference) => reference.dataset.tippy,
})
```